# Set sum(count) if item hasn't a serial number and set 1 if has one

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table invoice as

```
invoice_id
good_id
serial_number
count
```

and want to get stock report as :

```
good_id
serial_number
count
```

so , if good has serial_number then count should be 1, else count should be as sum of all counts from invoices

```
invoice_id good_id serial_number  count
1           1       123           1
1           2       456           1
1           3                     2
2           1       789
2           2       012
2           3                      3
```

output

```
good_id serial_number count
1       123            1
1       789            1  
2       456            1
2       012            1
3                      5
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.) https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: could you please add sample data and your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUM with CASE WHEN

```
SELECT good_id, serial_number, SUM(CASE WHEN serial_number IS NULL THEN count ELSE 1 END)
FROM invoice
GROUP BY good_id, serial_number
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Just should be "CASE WHEN serial_number IS NULL THEN count ELSE 1 END". Thanks! So easy!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT good_id, serial_number, (CASE WHEN serial_number IS NULL THEN SUM(count) ELSE 1 END) as sum_count
FROM invoice
GROUP BY good_id, serial_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    good_id,
    serial_number,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(A.Serial_Number,'') ='' 
    THEN
        (Select SUM(Count) from invoice  WHERE ISNULL(Serial_Number,'') ='' AND  good_id=A.good_id group by good_id) 
    ELSE 1 END As count
FROM invoice  AS A
```